# TLS origination from sidecar proxy instead of the Egress Gateway

Tags: istio

I am trying to setup mTLS for outgoing connections, but instead of originating the TLS traffic from the egress gateway, I’m trying to do it from the sidecar proxy itself. We want to originate the TLS connection from proxy and not the egress gateway.

I took care of mounting the client certs in my sidecar proxy container and verified that the client certs are available in the expected path. My API resources look something like below

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-host-mtls
spec:
  hosts:
  - external-host-example.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: external-mtls
spec:
  hosts:
  - external-host-example.com
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sniHosts:
        - external-host-example.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: external-host-example.com
        port:
          number: 443

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: external-mtls
spec:
  host: external-host-example.com
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      clientCertificate: /etc/client-certs/client.pem
      privateKey: /etc/client-certs/client.key
      caCertificates: /etc/client-certs/ca.pem
```

when I try to curl to external-host-example.com, I am hoping that Istio will add the client certs to the connection.
I’m not sure if that’s happening, because I’m running into errors.

```
curl -H "Host: external-host-example.com" --tlsv1.2 -v https://external-host-example.com

* About to connect() to external-host-example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connected to external-host-example.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
* Encountered end of file
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

Looking at the debug logs, I see this

```
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226367Z|debug|envoy filter|[external/envoy/source/extensions/filters/listener/tls_inspector/tls_inspector.cc:148] tls:onServerName(), requestedServerName: external-host-example.com|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226443Z|debug|envoy filter|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:251] [C161] new tcp proxy session|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226480Z|debug|envoy filter|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:395] [C161] Creating connection to cluster outbound|443||external-host-example.com|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226509Z|debug|envoy pool|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp/conn_pool.cc:83] creating a new connection|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226550Z|debug|envoy pool|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp/conn_pool.cc:364] [C162] connecting|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226557Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:727] [C162] connecting to x.x.x.x:443|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226641Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:736] [C162] connection in progress|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226656Z|debug|envoy pool|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp/conn_pool.cc:109] queueing request due to no available connections|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.226662Z|debug|envoy conn_handler|[external/envoy/source/server/connection_handler_impl.cc:411] [C161] new connection|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.252446Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:592] [C162] connected|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.252555Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:191] [C162] handshake expecting read|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.277388Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:191] [C162] handshake expecting read|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.277417Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:191] [C162] handshake expecting read|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.277595Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:176] [C162] handshake complete|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.277633Z|debug|envoy pool|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp/conn_pool.cc:285] [C162] assigning connection|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.277661Z|debug|envoy filter|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:624] TCP:onUpstreamEvent(), requestedServerName:external-host-example.com|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303804Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:226] [C162]|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303830Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:558] [C162] remote close|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303834Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:200] [C162] closing socket: 0|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303853Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:298] [C162] SSL shutdown: rc=-1|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303855Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:226] [C162]|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303880Z|debug|envoy pool|[external/envoy/source/common/tcp/conn_pool.cc:124] [C162] client disconnected|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303894Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:109] [C161] closing data_to_write=0 type=0|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303900Z|debug|envoy connection|[external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:200] [C161] closing socket: 1|
|2020-11-17T15:53:58.303985Z|debug|envoy conn_handler|[external/envoy/source/server/connection_handler_impl.cc:111] [C161] adding to cleanup list|
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? How do I debug this further?

Comment: (I am not on expert an that), but if you want to do TLS origination, should that curl call not use http? Otherwise there will be already an https connection between container and Istio proxy

Comment: Also in that question I have done something similar, though not with mTLS, but simple TLS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043896/service-entries-in-anthos-service-mesh

Comment: Could you try to add gateway with tls [passthrough](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/#ServerTLSSettings-TLSmode)? If I understand you're trying to do exactly the same thing as someone did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64056166/tls-handshake-through-istio-ingress-gateway-fails-tlsmode-passthrough).